# \pdfmarkupcomment works in MWE, but doesn't work in my thesis

Tags: hyperref, pdf, notes, pdfcomment

I have no idea why, but `\pdfmarkupcomment` doesn't show anything in my document. I tried to create MWE and it highlights text perfectly.

I guess some of the commands interfere with `pdfcomments`. Could someone help?

Here is my MWE (main file):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, BCOR=10mm]{scrbook} % see docs!
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\usepackage[ngerman, USenglish]{babel} % main language comes last!
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight, disable=false]{replication server}{what is this?}
\include{mwe2}
\end{document}
```

And include:

```
\chapter{Test}\label{chap:test}
\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight, disable=false]{replication server}{what is this?}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the information is not sufficient to give any kind of advice.

Comment: Then your MWE is not a proper MWE for your case. Make a copy of your thesis’ .tex file and begin commenting out stuff; a popular strategy is commenting out 50% and compiling. If the problem persists, go on, if not, use the other half, etc. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I understand. I checked the document once again. When I put \pdfmarkupcomment to the main file, then highlight works. When I put it to the file, which is included using \include{}, then highlight doesn't work for me

Comment: @damluar Can you construct a MWE using `\include`? (Btw, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) in posts as well as in comments.)

Comment: I posted MWE, I hope it will generate the same pdf as I have: the first page contains highlighted text and second - just usual text.

Comment: I don't see the problem with that MWE -- both ocurrances appear identical  Try opening the output file in Acrobat.

Comment: I've had a similar problem. Late but here is what I did: If it's just the highlighting that is not shown in some PDF viewers, I am combining `\hl{text}\pdfcomment{comment}` to get things to work. `\hl` is available via the `soul` package.