# \pdfmarkupcomment does not highlight what it is supposed to

Tags: pdfcomment

Basically I have the same problem as in the closed thread
[\pdfmarkupcomment works in MWE, but doesn't work in my thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98274/pdfmarkupcomment-works-in-mwe-but-doesnt-work-in-my-thesis).

Simple MWE, even longer files work fine, the text gets highlighted as it is supposed to.

My main paper consists out of several .tex-files (in different subdirectories) that get included (or not) depending on boolean variables.
Wheras other pdfcomment-commands work fine, the `pdfmarkupcomment` does not work at all.

Anybody seen something similar?

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce the [problem](https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/pdfcomment/issue/13/pdfmarkupcomment-not-visible-when-using). There seems to be a bug in `soulpos.sty`, which is used in `\pdfmarkupcomment`. When used in included files `soulpos.sty` only produces a `.upa` file but no `.upb` file. Therefore there are no positions to place the PDF annotation.

**soulpos.tex**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
%\newcommand\myinclude[1]{\clearpage\input{#1}}
\ulposdef{\ulflag}{%
\mbox{%
\color{red}\rule[-.85ex]{.25\ulwidth}{1.5pt}%
\color{yellow}\rule[-.85ex]{.5\ulwidth}{1.5pt}%
\color{red}\rule[-.85ex]{.25\ulwidth}{1.5pt}}}
\begin{document}
\include{./subdir/test}
\end{document}
```

**test.tex**

```
foo \ulflag{Test} bar
```

I already filed a bug report to Javier Bezos. Hopefully, he will be able to fix it asap.

As a workaround, which might break other features the usage of `\myinclude` instead of `\include` will work:

```
\newcommand\myinclude[1]{\clearpage\input{#1}}
```

Comment: Is there by chance any update on this? I was able to reproduce this issue in my thesis where I structured several sections across multiple files, included with `\input`. I don't really want to change all of the occurences...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem without using include files, but using some combination of packages (including, among many others, `lastpage`). I was able to fix the problem of the missing upb file by changing the following line in `soulpos.sty`

```
\write\@auxout{\string\ulp@afterend}%
```

to

```
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\ulp@afterend}%
```

(I've also suggested this as a bugfix to Javier Bezos, the author of `soulpos.sty`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Changing a distributed file is not really recommended.

Comment: @egreg You're right  - the author of soulpos.sty needs to change it, because it's a bug :-) As a workaround, add to the preamble of your own file(s)
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\ulp@afterend}}
\makeatother
(where \ulp@afterend is defined by soulpos.sty)

Comment: Coming back to this, I had another case where the upa file was never written: using `revtex4-1` together with `pdfcomments` did not work. This time, the fix was to include `\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\ulp@out=\jobname.upa\relax}`.