# makeidx and pdfcomment packages are not working together

Tags: indexing, pdfcomment

I noticed recently that if I'm using **pdfcomment** package together with **makeidx** in one document, highlighted comments are not added to the PDF output.
for example, you may run the following with LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

    \pdfmarkupcomment[author={Oleksandr},subject={test},color=green!25]{I will}{or, maybe not} put here some text, formulas, tables, comments, and some other things.
    Here comes a \index{formula} formula.

    \clearpage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
    \printindex

\end{document}
```

and see that in the output no comments are added.
However, if you comment out lines

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
```

and

```
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex
```

and re-run the typeset, you will see that comment is now added.
Workaround is obvious - first, run the document without **makeidx** package, and then add it in the end, but it is not very good.

Why is there such behavior of the **pdfcomment** package and how to fix it?

**Edited:**

I accept answer of **egreg**, however, I see some strange behavior of **imakeidx** in my computer. To illustrate it, I put a picture there, so you can see that sub-entry of the index is not formatted properly.
[image: imakeidx not working properly]

Comment: It's not `makeidx`; just a `\clearpage` command suffices.

Comment: I just tried to comment out \clearpage command in the initial source code, but it did not help. Or, what do you mean?

Comment: if I remove \clearpage and \printindex, then it works. but it still does not solve the issue.

Comment: It's kind of a known problem of `soulpos.sty` (only used by `pdfmarkupcomment` - it works e.g. with `pdftooltip`). Under certain circumstances `soulpos.sty` only produces its `upa` files but no `upb` (with the positions) files, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132973/pdfmarkupcomment-does-not-highlight-what-it-is-supposed-to and https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/pdfcomment/issue/13/pdfmarkupcomment-not-visible-when-using. I contacted Javier Be­zos but unfortunately never got a reply.

Comment: Same problem without `pdfcomment`: \documentclass{report}
\usepackage{soulpos}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\ulposdef{\ulflag}{%
\mbox{%
\color{red}\rule[-.85ex]{.25\ulwidth}{1.5pt}%
\color{yellow}\rule[-.85ex]{.5\ulwidth}{1.5pt}%
\color{red}\rule[-.85ex]{.25\ulwidth}{1.5pt}}}
\begin{document}
\ulflag{TestTestTest}
\clearpage
\end{document}

Comment: well, sometimes things just go out of the control.

Comment: As workaround, temporarily delete `\clearpage`. Once the `upb` file is created by `soulpos.sty`, `pdfcomment` can place the comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is quite subtle. If the index has not yet been compiled, the `\clearpage` command does essentially nothing and there is no next page, so `pdfcomment` can't complete its job, because no page is shipped out after the one in which the comment is.

Solution: use `imakeidx` that also avoid the need of a separate run of MakeIndex.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\chapter{X}

\pdfmarkupcomment[
  author={Oleksandr},
  subject={test},
  color=green!25,
]{I will}{or, maybe not}
put here some text, formulas, tables, comments, and some other things.
Here comes a \index{formula} formula.


\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in this case I'm loosing possibility to use makeidx sub-entries of form \index{formula!variance!way one}. they do not work in the same way in imakeidx.

Comment: @Oleksandr really?

Comment: i tried, and it produces some strange output. with makeidx subentry is placed as it should - under main entry with indentation. with imakeidx it is placed on the same line with main entry. just put \index{formula!test} to your code and typeset it, and you will see.

Comment: @Oleksandr No, I can't see it: “test” is placed below “formula” and indented. You are mistaken by the fact that `imakeidx` balances the last column.

Comment: I updated my question with illustration of the output for me, so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Oleksandr If you don't want the index to have its last column balanced, call `\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}`; but what you see in that image is no error: it's just that the subentry goes to the second column because of balancing.